# Migrating from TFVC to GitHub for large SQL solution

Tags: database, git, github, version-control, tfvc

The team I work in is currently migrating from TFVC to GitHub for a large database solution.

When making changes to either code, objects or SSIS packages in TFVC from Visual Studio, they appear "Checked Out" (red tick). So only one Developer can make a change once checked out. Other Developers will see the object checked out and it will be read only until checked back in. VS also displays which Developer has the object checked out so aids communication between the team when they are making multiple changes.

This ensure Developers always commit to the main branch, in sequence. No branching, that has proven to avoid accidental BUGs.

We are having a hard time understanding how to migrate to GitHub, as having the above functionality in TFVC seems vital in a database solution as the logic needs committing in a sequential chain, no branching.

Has anyone had the same difficulties they've overcame or decided GitHub isn't suitable for database projects?

Thanks,

Trying to overcome not being able to individually check out code.

Comment: You'll need to become comfortable with merging changes when 2 people make changes at the same time, or you'll need to agree with other developers to use a different technique to signal that someone is editing the files.

Comment: Yes, there is a higher chance of issues when having to merge code, that applies to all code, not just SQL. If developers of all kinds of other languages and platforms can handle this, surely so can your team with some practice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is we have a solution with literally 1000's of procs, views, tables etc and introducing a new element of risk merging changes is worrying. I'm surprised that there isnt an option to force check-out to read only for other developers tbh..

Comment: Given that Git works on a complete local clone of the repository and given that in git you don't always talk to a single "blessed remote" instance but potentially a network of forks of the same repository, there is no single place where you can enforce the lock. Its a fundamentally different approach to versioning than TFVC, though you can use git in a simple client/server scenario, it's definitely not the scenario git is optimized for.

Comment: But to counter your argument, I have a number of code solutions with literally 10000's of code files and multiple devs working against it. The Azure DevOps team used to have 800 devs working on their product, which includes a huge database schema. The Windows team and the Office team are working in Git over at Micsosoft. The whole of GitHub is build in a set of git repositories. It can be done, but you may need to put in place some automation (CI workflow in GitHub Actions for example) and use Pull Requests with reviews to ensure that people don't mess up the schema or introduce bugs.

Comment: Even TFVC has long moved from server workspaces with exclusive locking to local workspaces with optimistic checkouts. The default configuration of a new TFVC repo would be to not enable exclusive checkout at all.

Comment: Thanks for your expertise, much appreciated. Will feed back to team. We have to migrate, company policy, so will test test and test again around merges to fully understand how to avoid issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to become comfortable with merging changes when 2 people make changes at the same time, or you'll need to agree with other developers to use a different technique to signal that someone is editing the files.

Yes, there is a higher chance of issues when having to merge code, which applies to all code, not just SQL. If developers of all kinds of other languages and platforms can handle this, surely so can your team with some practice. But I fully understand this may cause problems in the meantime.

Given that Git works on a complete local clone of the repository and given that in git you don't always talk to a single "blessed remote" instance but potentially a network of forks of the same repository, there is no single place where you can enforce the lock. It's a fundamentally different approach to versioning than TFVC, though you can use git in a simple client/server scenario, it's definitely not the scenario git is optimized for.

But to counter your argument, I have a number of code solutions with literally 10000's of code files and multiple devs working against it. The Azure DevOps team used to have 800 devs working on their product, which includes a huge database schema. The Windows team and the Office team are working in Git over at Microsoft. The whole of GitHub is built in a set of git repositories. It can be done, but you may need to put in place some automation (CI workflow in GitHub Actions for example) and use Pull Requests with reviews to ensure that people don't mess up the schema or introduce bugs.

Even TFVC has long moved from server workspaces with exclusive locking to local workspaces with optimistic checkouts. The default configuration of a new TFVC repo would be to not enable exclusive checkout at all.

Answer (score 0):

In normal git usage, we prefer to handle and commit only text files that are mergeable.

But if you really need to lock files that are not mergeable, for example binary files, you should use a git server supporting 'git-lfs' https://git-lfs.com/.

That way you will be able to lock some files ( with `git lfs lock` https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-lfs/git-lfs-lock.1.en.html ) and no other dev will be able to push a change to this file until it is unlocked.

But as git is decentralized, devs still can work and commit offline, nothing will prevent them to update locked files locally and commit them.

But you could still list the files locked before starting to work on it with https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/git-lfs-locks.1.html

And we could also imagine to write a hook preventing to commit a file locked or outputing a warning..,

Comment: Keep in mind that GitHub charges separately for LFS storage and network traffic and that it adds a few wonderful new edge cases to how git works.